# What is the purpose of last value caching in networking?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, network-programming

In a messaging system what is the purpose of last value caching? I understand it gives access tot he previous item but why is that so useful compared to say a "fire and forget" approach and if you are a client just remembering the last value. What use cases am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last value can be used for checking if the message arrived correctly from sender to recipient, if not, the client can resend the message again until the message arrives intact and cannot send new message until then(which is highly advisable, because you don't want to send bad data). In fire and forget scenario, if the sender client wanted to do a check, there would be no data to check and possibility of damaged data would be high. Or you would have to go through hoops to give sender access to that data even if it is not cached, but that is a lot of pain and also not very secure.

And that is just one use for caching of last value.

Comment: Thanks! If you wanted to tell me another I'd me super grateful but I'm going to accept you answer now.